# Building Soap Security header from pl/sql

Tags: soap, plsql, soapui

I have a requirement to send soap request messages directly from oracle DB via pl/sql to the target system. I would have to build the security header programmatically which will be appended to the soap request then.The values for wsse:username and wsse.Password will remain the same for security header for all soap requests. My question is how can I dynamically generate values for following elements through pl/sql

wsu:Timestamp which has Id, created and expires elements.
wsse:UsernameToken

I believe UsernameToken is a one time generation and then I can re-use that with multiple soap requests. But the created and expires elements of Timestamp should be generated each time when sending the WS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows how to add Timestamp and UsernameToken with the commercial [ORA_XML](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-rsa/tutorial/soap/#timestamp) package:

```
declare
  encode_password BOOLEAN;
  seconds_valid INT;
  
  signed_soap CLOB;
  soap_data CLOB;
begin

    soap_data := '...';
        
    -- when TRUE only a digest of password is encoded, 
    -- when FALSE the password appears inside the message    
    encode_password := TRUE;
    -- Time of validity of the Timestamp signature
    -- 0 = valid forever
    seconds_valid := 300; 
    
    signed_soap := ORA_XML.SOAP_WSS_USERNAME_SIGN_TIMESTAMP(soap_data, 'user', 'pass', encode_password, seconds_valid);
                                     
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('signed_data=' || signed_soap);
end;
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft